# Submitting form after changing input by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I got HTML like this:

```
<table>
    <form action=\'food.php\' method=\'POST\'>
    <tr><h4>
        <td><span><input type="submit" name="food_edit" class="food_edit" value="Edytuj" /></span></td>
       </h4>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

And then a function in jQuery which change input field:

```
wrap.find('.food_edit')
    .replaceWith('<input type=\'submit\' name=\'food_edit_confirm\' value=\'Potwierdź\' />');
```

My problem is that after change submitting button, send form doesn't work.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: `h4` should have been inside the `td`tags, and `form` probably wrapping the `table`

Comment: If you fix your HTML it works.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this after replacement of submit button:

```
$('form').on('click','input[type=submit]',function(){
   //rest of code goes here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you either need to use $( document ).ready() around the particular jquery code or u can try and use the .attr to change the attribs of your class or u can use 'focus' to wrap around it. or u can do something like

```
$('form').live('submit',function(){
// do the rest of ur code and then submit it....
});
```

Comment: Nice effort but `.live()` is deprecated since 1.8 version :)

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML. It should look like this:

```
<form action=\'food.php\' method=\'POST\'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" name="food_edit" class="food_edit" value="Edytuj" />
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

If you're looking to add a confirmation you should look into the `onsubmit=""` in the `<form>` tag.

Example:

```
<form action=\'food.php\' method=\'POST\' onsubmit=\'return checkForm();\'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" name="food_edit" class="food_edit" value="Edytuj" />
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

JS Code:

```
function checkForm() {
    return confirm("Submit this form?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.food_edit').replaceWith("<input type='submit' name='food_edit_confirm' value='Potwierdz' onclick='document.getElementById(\"submit\").click();' />");

});
</script>


<form action='food.php' method='POST'>
        <input type="submit" name="food_edit" class="food_edit" value="Edytuj" onclick="document.getElementById('submit').click();" />
        <input type="submit" style="display:none" id="submit" />
    </form>
```

The hidden button always do submit the form regardless you do anything with the submit button which is replacable.